# A dynamic site that does not use JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, django, dynamic

I started using the python django framework.  Can I open a dynamic site without using JavaScript?  I find python easy to use and for some reason I don't like JavaScript.

Comment: Depends on what your definition of dynamic is

Comment: For example, to display the next message without updating the site when you click the button

Comment: Something like this -> https://www.transcrypt.org/

Comment: << I don't like JavaScript >> ! As a developer, it's a valid reason to learn JS. **You don't have to love it**, but **to know it** a lot to do your work well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*; we can't help you design a project at the top level, and we aren't interested in your opinions about various programming languages etc. "open a dynamic site" is not remotely specific enough of a problem for us to help with, because there is no indication of what the code actually has to *do*.

Comment: _to display the next message without updating the site when you click the button_ I don't understand this.  If you're displaying the next message, then clearly something is being **updated**.  Do you mean without **reloading** the page?

Answer (score 3):

In order to implement dynamic elements (such as displaying messages at button click without updating the site) you need to instruct the browser to change the respective DOM elements.

Currently the only fully supported language that browsers understand for that purpose is Javascript.

There are Javascript alternatives such as Dart or Typescript, but they need to be transpiled to Javascript to work with browsers.

So, practically you cannot build a dynamic website without Javascript at the moment.